# Name and Unnamed Semaphore

Tags: posix, semaphore

I'm trying to understand the similarities and differences between named and unnamed semaphore so my google searches yielded me [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5137/sync-39/index.html). I had a question about the wording on the page though, it says:

- Unnamed semaphores might be **usable** by more than one process
- Named semaphores are **sharable** by several processes

Do those two words create any important distinction between those two types of semaphores or are they irrelevant?

So so far here's what I have:

```
Similarities
    -Several processes can do something with the semaphore

Difference
    -Named are referenced with pathname and unnamed are referenced by pshared value
```

That's all I could glean from that definition. Is that everything and are they correct? Or am I missing some significant concept?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Think in terms of *who* can access the semaphore.

Unnamed semaphores (lacking any name or handle to locate them) must exist in some pre-existing, agreed upon memory location.  Usually that is (1) shared memory (inherited by children after `fork`) in the case of child processes; or (2) shared memory, global variable or the heap in the case where they are shared between threads of a single process.  The essential thing here is that the code in parent, child, or threads already knows the address of the semaphore.

Named semaphores are necessary for unrelated processes.  For example a producer and consumer might be written by two different developers and run as completely unrelated processes.  But they have to share some resource that needs to be protected by a semaphore.  The named semaphore gives them a path to the semaphore.

In reality you can use a named semaphore in all scenarios but they come with a little extra baggage because you have to deal with the paths and permissions and such that are unnecessary if the programs are related and already know how to access an unnamed semaphore.  It's a little silly, for instance, to use a named semaphore to share a resource between threads.  The threads already have access to the same memory where an unnamed semaphore could reside.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is wrong (as well as the other one given by @electron). Unnamed POSIX semaphores *can* be used by unrelated processes. You just have to store the data structure in shared memory accessible by the relevant processes and init it with the shareable flag set to one, as shown here (shamelessly copied from http://blog.superpat.com/2010/07/14/semaphores-on-linux-sem_init-vs-sem_open/):

```
int shm;
sem_t * mutex;

if ((shm = shm_open("myshm", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU))   0) {
    perror("shm_open");
    exit(1);
}

if (ftruncate(shm, sizeof(sem_t)) < 0 ) {
    perror("ftruncate");
    exit(1);
}

if ((mutex = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0)) == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(1);
}

if (sem_init(mutex, 1, 1) < 0) {
    perror("semaphore initialization");
    exit(1);
}
```

Another process mapping that shared memory into its address space can access the same semaphore and synchronize with the original process. See also the POSIX specification of [sem_init()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_init.html) and its [linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html).

Answer (score -2):

**Named semaphore** has an `actual name` in the `file system` and can be `shared` by multiple ***unrelated processes***.

**Unnamed semaphores** can be used only by `threads` belonging to the ***same process***.

**semaphores** are *created* using the function

```
                 sem init(ptr_semaphore, flag, initial_value);
```

where

**ptr_semaphore**: a pointer to semaphore

**flag**: a flag indicating level of sharing

**initial_value**: semaphores's initial value

If you pass `flag=0` to `sem_init()` then **semaphore** can
be **shared only by threads belonging to the process** that created the semaphore.Thus it will create **unamed semaphore**.

```
          sem_init(ptr_semaphore,0,initial_value)   //unamed semaphore
```

Passing a **nonzero value** would `allow` **other processes to access the semaphore as well**. Thus it will result in **named semaphore**.

```
          sem_init(ptr_semaphore,1,initial_value)   //named semaphore
```

Comment: "Unnamed semaphores can be used only by threads belonging to the same process" - Wrong.